# Error says table doesn't exist in database, while it exists

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have extracted list of names of tables in database using this sql query:

```
"SELECT table_name from information_schema.tables"
```

I got this list:

```
    table_name
1   main_table
2   kp_table
3   ids_table
4   main_logs
```

Then i want to extract table ids_table:

```
"SELECT * from ids_table"
```

So desired result is to get that table, but i get this error:

```
Error: Failed to prepare query: ERROR:  relation "ids_table" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * from ids_table
```

Why it happens? Why i get from first query its name, but then it tells me that it doesn't exist?

Comment: Check schema like dbo.Ids_table (is default) other schema need wirte after table name

Comment: Can you add the schema name to the query from information_schema?

Comment: @Mureinik i don't know it

Comment: Have you tried adding the schema_name in front of the table name like `SELECT * FROM schema.ids_table`

Comment: If you don't know the schema you can display it using `select table_schema, table_name from information_schema.tables`

Comment: Can you try this SELECT * from information_schema.ids_table

Comment: @Mureinik you should get PGADMIN. That will help you view the content of the database visually. I think that might help you

Comment: @NafiuLawal I think that comment was directed to @ french_fries

Answer (score 2):

In this case, I would say that the most common issue is that you are looking at two different databases.  That is probably not the cause in this case.

Another common possibility is that the schema is something unexpected, and you should be referencing the schema.  For that, include the schema in the query:

```
select table_schema, table_name
from information_schema.tables
```

Another possibility are hidden characters, such as spaces.  You can see if this is the problem by adding delimiters so check the names:

```
select '|' || table_name || '|'
from information_schema.tables
```

Comment: yeah it was schema reference problem

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to select data from different schema, which by default owns by different user, but you have access to it. As this table is not created by user, which you are using for select * from ... , you must indicate schemas name before table name. Without schemas name it's trying to select date from users schema, but actually table are owned by completely different user.